# How to make a publicly available contact form in rails served via CDN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to place a contact form (email, name, message) in public facing pages in my rails app. I want to serve them via a CDN (say Cloudflare). The pages then will be cached by the CDN, including the authenticity_token in the form and the csrf-token in the meta tag.

What is the best way to handle this in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching an authenticity token and csrf-token basically make them useless.

If you intent to go forward, you need an open form that doesn't pretend to secure itself.  You'll need lots of defenses against spam and should not trust anything submitted via the action.

I'm not sure why you would do this as you're unlikely to get that much contact form traffic to require caching it like that.  Just let rails render a normal form is my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The contact form is part of a page that I would like to serve fast, hence the CDN requirement. I will try to move the contact form away from the page, to another uncached route.